# How to normalize a MySQL database in a 'social media' type application

Tags: mysql, database, database-normalization

We have 2 tables as a starting point in a MySQL database for a 'social media' type WebApp:

**People** - there can be an unlimited and ever growing number of people (users) `[A,B,C,D,E,F, ...]`. Each person has a unique ID.

**Groups** - there can be an unlimited and ever growing number of groups created by users `[G1, G2, G3, G4, G5, G6, ...]`. Each group group has a unique ID.

A person can belong to as many groups as they like `B.groups=[G1,G3,G5, ...]`.

A group can have an unlimited number of persons. `G2.people=[A, C, H, Z, ...]`.

We need to efficiently query all the groups that a person belongs to and efficiently query all the people who belong to a group. Creating a table for each **person** to list groups and each **group** to list persons would result in a very large number of tables.

I understand that having tables with multiple 'null' values and a very large number of columns is inefficient and that including an array in a field is bad practice - that I need to 'normalize'. I just can't get my head around the table format that could normalize this data requirement. I have been reading many pages on SO and other material such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

I have considered a table **Memberships** with only 2 columns: `GroupID` & `PersonID`, where each individual relationship is stored. The table may get very long. Would this be good practice? Otherwise, please provide suggestions.

Comment: Your membershiptable with 2 columns is correct. But make sure you add an index for the other column order (if `groupid, personid` is your primary key, add an index for `personid, groupid`, or vice versa), otherwise, one of the two queries to list all the groups that a person belongs to and tolist all the people who belong to a group will be slow (but not incorrect).

Comment: Time to read an introductory textbook on information modeling & relational databases. (Dozens are online free, also academic slide & courses.)

Comment: Yes, People and Groups are in a many-to-many relationship. This kind of relationship is established with a linking table. Memberships is your linking table.